# dijit form filteringselect not support options in EL variable?

Tags: spring, variables, dojo, el

There is a very beautiful solution in spring to populate up a select list from EL variable such as:

```
<form:select id="customerentity_customerTitle" path="customerTitle" cssStyle="width:300px;">
    <form:option value="None" label="*** Select Your Title ***"></form:option>
    <form:options items="${fn:split(title_t, ',')}" />
</form:select>
```

This JSTL and spring solution can be applied easily and very affection.

When I tried to find a similar solution in Dojo. I found most close solution is dijit/form/FilteringSelect, but when I try to use similar way to populate a dynamic generated dropdown select, it doesn't work.

```
<select id="customerentity_customerTitle" name="customerTitle" style="width: 300px;" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" 
    data-dojo-props="value: '${customerentity.customerTitle}',placeHolder: 'Select Your Title',options:'${fn:split(title_t, ',')}'">
</select>
```

My question is: Is there any possible to use similar way to do it in digit/form/FilteringSelect? or I have to do it by using javascript to populate it?

Any advice is welcome!!

**Edit**

title was hold in a property file and access by using:

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="bundles.customer-resources" />
```

resources bundle.

The sources looks like:

```
storageway.customer.person.title.options=Mr.,Ms.,Mrs.,Dr.,Other
```

access by:

```
<fmt:message key="storageway.customer.person.title.options" var="title_t" scope="session" />
```

It is a simple string array instead of a key:value map. Spring form can handle it properly but dijit/form/FilteringSelect not.

Answer (score 0):

You can create normal `option` tags inside the `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`.
They will be rendered. So I bet you can do

```
<select id="customerentity_customerTitle" name="customerTitle" style="width: 300px;" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" 
data-dojo-props="value: '${customerentity.customerTitle}',placeHolder: 'Select Your Title'">

    <form:options items="${fn:split(title_t, ',')}" />
</select>
```

See the snippet:

```js
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parser){
    parser.parse();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">

<div class="tundra">
  
  <select id="customerentity_customerTitle" name="customerTitle" style="width: 300px;" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" 
    data-dojo-props="value: 'b',placeHolder: 'Select Your Title'">
    
    <option value="a">value A</option>
    <option value="b">value B</option>
    <option value="c">value C</option>
  </select> 
  
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your advice. Your solution is not work for my situation. The select items was defined in my property file, this items is not a map format but it is only a simple string array. It can only be accessed by EL.